# /Fe (Name EXE File) is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, windows-7, exe

I would like to compile a cpp source file in windows 7, visual studio 2010 using

`Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64`

When I do the following

`>cl /EHs main.cpp -o test`

I got

`cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release`

Ok fair enough. I've checked this page [/Fe (Name EXE File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/kc584260.aspx). This option is not working with me.It gives me this error

```
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'test', object file assumed
main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
test
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'test.obj'
```

Now how should I activate this option? I always find it difficult to read `MSDN Library`. It is not friendly at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there is no space between `/Fe` and the file name.

```
cl /EHs /Fetest.exe main.cpp
```

Alternatively, you can use the colon syntax:

```
cl /EHs /Fe: test.exe main.cpp
```

Comment: no kidding. Is it because they should not be spaced??????? This is just weird, absolutely weird. Thanks it worked. `/Fe: ` is not working with me though.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve same thing using

```
cl /Ehs main.cpp /link /OUT:test.exe
```

`/link` tells cl to pass these options to linker and `/OUT` specifies the name of output file.

Comment: it worked. I'm not sure but I don't feel ok to use `/link` since I know the compiler will do it. Is there a reason not to use `-o` or even `/o`?

Comment: There is no `-o` or `/o` in cl options. You should not use any deprecated options as it might not work in future version.